# Reproducing a bug in production that happens with a large database

Tags: testing, relational-database

We are running Oracle 12c and a custom application written in Java/JDBC (Java 8). Our production system is running a 5TB database and runs into deadlocks. However we have been unable to reproduce this in our test environment which is considerably smaller. Unfortunately we don't have a test system that can handle 5TB. We don't know why database size should matter when it comes to database deadlocks. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the size of the database but rather the number of concurrent users updating rows.

Comment: Deadlocks can be caused by poorly written SQL in the application or ORM.  Some schema designs don't scale well. More information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Thread profiler to identify the real root cause of your production environment. Most of the time, it might be due to heavy traffic. If you really wants to make a copy of your production db(at least a part of it as a QA db) use slony to replicate data from the production to some other database.